# How can I load a .html file into processing?

Tags: processing

In my project, I want to convert an old electric typewriter to a rudimentary type of printer. Because I'll be using an Arduino Uno to imitate the typewriter keyboard, I will have to send the commands via USB because the Arduino has very low EEPROM Size. So my idea was to make a processing sketch which converts the file (I thought of .html because its structure is simple but it features formatting text, if anyone has a better idea please let me know) into commands for the Uno. Does anyone of you know how to open such a file and eventually converting it into a .txt with the commands?

Comment: An html file is already text.

Answer (score 1):

To load an html file, you can use the [loadStrings()](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) method:

```
String[] lines = loadStrings("http://processing.org/about/index.html");
```

This will read the contents of a file and creates a String array of its individual lines. You can then either remove HTML tags from every String in the `lines` array one by one, or write the `lines` array into a txt file and remove all the HTML tags from there. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow with good answers how that can be done.

I did not quite understand what you meant by the fact that HTML features formatting text, but other approach you could consider possibly is XML (use [loadXML()](https://processing.org/reference/loadXML_.html) method) or JSON. Parsers for those into text are also readily available.